# Visual Studio 2013 - Automating some input with a macro

Tags: c#, visual-studio, automation, macros

I find myself entering the boilerplate code for the logger in a lot of project I am working on.

In one project, I use:

```
DebugLog.Error(GetType(), "Message");
```

Is there a way to automate some of this with a macro or autocomplete where I could press a hotkey and have:

```
DebugLog.Error(GetType(), "");
```

show up with the cursor between the quotation marks?

I was unable to find a way to do this or even the terms to ask about in general.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Code Snippet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) or a [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) command to insert such text.